# Format textbox to display date "dd M yy"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, datepicker, date-format

I have a textbox with dates out of a database, the dates are in the following format:

> 2012/06/12 12:00:00 AM

That is what they display in the textbox.

I want them to display "dd M yy"

> 06 Jun 2012

How can Format the textbox to display the date like this.

I can get today's date to display in this format with the following code:

```
    $('.DatePicker').datepicker({       
            dateFormat: "dd M yy"
        });
$('.DatePicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Answer (score 3):

This question was already asked.  There are lots of reasonable answers here:

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

My suggestion is that you use DateJS.  It will allow you to use the toString('dd M yy') formatting you're looking for.

http://www.DateJS.com